# axis 0 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0

Tags: numpy, opencv, python-3.6

I am trying to create a watermark identifier but receiving the error

> AxisError: axis 0 is out of bounds for an array of dimension 0

it seems to me matrix issue but I am unable to understand it. can anyone please make me understand this error code

below are my codes:

```
import sys, os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import warnings
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy
import scipy, scipy.fftpack

# Variables
KERNEL_SIZE = 3

def estimate_watermark(foldername):
    """
    Given a folder, estimate the watermark (grad(W) = median(grad(J)))
    Also, give the list of gradients, so that further processing can be done on it
    """
    if not os.path.exists(foldername):
        warnings.warn("Folder does not exist.", UserWarning)
        return None

    images = []
    for r, dirs, files in os.walk(foldername):
        # Get all the images
        for file in files:
            img = cv2.imread(os.sep.join([r, file]))
            if img is not None:
                images.append(img)
            else:
                print("%s not found."%(file))

    # Compute gradients
    print("Computing gradients.")
    gradx = map(lambda x: cv2.Sobel(x, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=KERNEL_SIZE), images)
    grady = map(lambda x: cv2.Sobel(x, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=KERNEL_SIZE), images)
    print(type(gradx))
    print(type(grady))

    # Compute median of grads
    print("Computing median gradients.")
    Wm_x = np.median(np.array(gradx), axis=0)#it occurs here                    
    Wm_y = np.median(np.array(grady), axis=0)

    return (Wm_x, Wm_y, gradx, grady)


def PlotImage(image):
    """ 
    PlotImage: Give a normalized image matrix which can be used with implot, etc.
    Maps to [0, 1]
    """
    im = image.astype(float)
    return (im - np.min(im))/(np.max(im) - np.min(im))


def poisson_reconstruct2(gradx, grady, boundarysrc):
    # Thanks to Dr. Ramesh Raskar for providing the original matlab code from which this is derived
    # Dr. Raskar's version is available here: http://web.media.mit.edu/~raskar/photo/code.pdf

    # Laplacian
    gyy = grady[1:,:-1] - grady[:-1,:-1]
    gxx = gradx[:-1,1:] - gradx[:-1,:-1]
    f = numpy.zeros(boundarysrc.shape)
    f[:-1,1:] += gxx
    f[1:,:-1] += gyy

    # Boundary image
    boundary = boundarysrc.copy()
    boundary[1:-1,1:-1] = 0;

    # Subtract boundary contribution
    f_bp = -4*boundary[1:-1,1:-1] + boundary[1:-1,2:] + boundary[1:-1,0:-2] + boundary[2:,1:-1] + boundary[0:-2,1:-1]
    f = f[1:-1,1:-1] - f_bp

    # Discrete Sine Transform
    tt = scipy.fftpack.dst(f, norm='ortho')
    fsin = scipy.fftpack.dst(tt.T, norm='ortho').T

    # Eigenvalues
    (x,y) = numpy.meshgrid(range(1,f.shape[1]+1), range(1,f.shape[0]+1), copy=True)
    denom = (2*numpy.cos(math.pi*x/(f.shape[1]+2))-2) + (2*numpy.cos(math.pi*y/(f.shape[0]+2)) - 2)

    f = fsin/denom

    # Inverse Discrete Sine Transform
    tt = scipy.fftpack.idst(f, norm='ortho')
    img_tt = scipy.fftpack.idst(tt.T, norm='ortho').T

    # New center + old boundary
    result = boundary
    result[1:-1,1:-1] = img_tt

    return result


def poisson_reconstruct(gradx, grady, kernel_size=KERNEL_SIZE, num_iters=100, h=0.1, 
        boundary_image=None, boundary_zero=True):
    """
    Iterative algorithm for Poisson reconstruction. 
    Given the gradx and grady values, find laplacian, and solve for image
    Also return the squared difference of every step.
    h = convergence rate
    """
    fxx = cv2.Sobel(gradx, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=kernel_size)
    fyy = cv2.Sobel(grady, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=kernel_size)
    laplacian = fxx + fyy
    m,n,p = laplacian.shape

    if boundary_zero == True:
        est = np.zeros(laplacian.shape)
    else:
        assert(boundary_image is not None)
        assert(boundary_image.shape == laplacian.shape)
        est = boundary_image.copy()

    est[1:-1, 1:-1, :] = np.random.random((m-2, n-2, p))
    loss = []

    for i in xrange(num_iters):
        old_est = est.copy()
        est[1:-1, 1:-1, :] = 0.25*(est[0:-2, 1:-1, :] + est[1:-1, 0:-2, :] + est[2:, 1:-1, :] + est[1:-1, 2:, :] - h*h*laplacian[1:-1, 1:-1, :])
        error = np.sum(np.square(est-old_est))
        loss.append(error)

    return (est)


def image_threshold(image, threshold=0.5):
    '''
    Threshold the image to make all its elements greater than threshold*MAX = 1
    '''
    m, M = np.min(image), np.max(image)
    im = PlotImage(image)
    im[im >= threshold] = 1
    im[im < 1] = 0
    return im


def crop_watermark(gradx, grady, threshold=0.4, boundary_size=2):
    """
    Crops the watermark by taking the edge map of magnitude of grad(W)
    Assumes the gradx and grady to be in 3 channels
    @param: threshold - gives the threshold param
    @param: boundary_size - boundary around cropped image
    """
    W_mod = np.sqrt(np.square(gradx) + np.square(grady))
    W_mod = PlotImage(W_mod)
    W_gray = image_threshold(np.average(W_mod, axis=2), threshold=threshold)
    x, y = np.where(W_gray == 1)

    xm, xM = np.min(x) - boundary_size - 1, np.max(x) + boundary_size + 1
    ym, yM = np.min(y) - boundary_size - 1, np.max(y) + boundary_size + 1

    return gradx[xm:xM, ym:yM, :] , grady[xm:xM, ym:yM, :]


def normalized(img):
    """
    Return the image between -1 to 1 so that its easier to find out things like 
    correlation between images, convolutionss, etc.
    Currently required for Chamfer distance for template matching.
    """
    return (2*PlotImage(img)-1)

def watermark_detector(img, gx, gy, thresh_low=200, thresh_high=220, printval=False):
    """
    Compute a verbose edge map using Canny edge detector, take its magnitude.
    Assuming cropped values of gradients are given.
    Returns image, start and end coordinates
    """
    Wm = (np.average(np.sqrt(np.square(gx) + np.square(gy)), axis=2))

    img_edgemap = (cv2.Canny(img, thresh_low, thresh_high))
    chamfer_dist = cv2.filter2D(img_edgemap.astype(float), -1, Wm)

    rect = Wm.shape
    index = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(chamfer_dist), img.shape[:-1])
    if printval:
        print(index)

    x,y = (index[0]-rect[0]/2), (index[1]-rect[1]/2)
    im = img.copy()
    cv2.rectangle(im, (y, x), (y+rect[1], x+rect[0]), (255, 0, 0))
    return (im, (x, y), (rect[0], rect[1]))
```

can anyone please help on this...as it seems like matrix issue

```
  File "<ipython-input-6-0e709e7207fd>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/prince.bhatia/Desktop/automatic-watermark-detection-master/automatic-watermark-detection-master/Watermarking.py', wdir='C:/Users/prince.bhatia/Desktop/automatic-watermark-detection-master/automatic-watermark-detection-master')

  File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/prince.bhatia/Desktop/automatic-watermark-detection-master/automatic-watermark-detection-master/Watermarking.py", line 4, in <module>
    gx, gy, gxlist, gylist = estimate_watermark('images/fotolia_processed')

  File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\Desktop\automatic-watermark-detection-master\automatic-watermark-detection-master\src\estimate_watermark.py", line 41, in estimate_watermark
    Wm_x = np.median(np.array(gradx), axis=0)

  File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 4102, in median
    overwrite_input=overwrite_input)

  File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3997, in _ureduce
    axis = _nx.normalize_axis_tuple(axis, nd)

  File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 1536, in normalize_axis_tuple
    axis = tuple(normalize_axis_index(ax, ndim, argname) for ax in axis)

  File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 1536, in <genexpr>
    axis = tuple(normalize_axis_index(ax, ndim, argname) for ax in axis)

AxisError: axis 0 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0
```

Comment: I can't tell from a quick scroll where the error occurs.  Do you know what it means to have dimension 0?

Comment: Please post only the relevant code which causes the error? Also a full Traceback of error message would be appreciable. Probably your matrix is empty (width, height = 0) and you are trying some operation on it, which throws an error as the matrix is empty.

Comment: Hi,I have posted my full error code

Comment: FYI, your code does not produce any error if I run it. It looks like those functions are never called in your code. Perhaps you should produce a proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular, you should provide the input data, which is likely where the problem actually is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the error is in the first function.  All the rest of the code is irrelevant.

It's taking the `median` of a `map` call.  In python3, `map(...)` isn't evaluated; you need `list(map(...))`.

My guess is that `median` does `np.array(map....)` which produces a 0d array object dtype and hence the error.

I think I've seen this kind of error before.

What did the

```
print(type(gradx))
```

show?